# Is my website test approach comprehensive enough?

Tags: selenium, web, test-strategy

I am working on a test automation project for a webpage portal.

What I want to achieve is:

1. Perform a HTML encoding conformance test; I have noticed that there are a number of missing tags, un-escaped characters and etc in its HTML.
2. Spider this web and index all items for comparison purpose; by doing this, I can find out if a new element is added or if an element is missing.
3. Take a snap shot of the Q&A section as I have noticed a large portion of its text is not in English. After the developers (based in a foreign country) write Q&A in English, I want to make sure texts stay in English.
4. Click on all "link" elements, making sure they are valid, e.g. there is no 404.
5. Implement automated tests on filling a form, inputting a password, making a choice from a drop down list and etc. (This is the bulk of this project)

Is there any other things I am missing from my list?

Thanks

Comment: Is this for a single page, or for a set of pages?  Are they static, or dynamically generated?

Comment: @KevinMcKenzie, it is for a set of pages. They are static but can change if new features are introduced.

Comment: And this is what sort of testing?  Functional?

Comment: @KevinMcKenzie, testing in general, should include both functional and non-functional.

Comment: Yes, but depending on what your goals are, different sorts of testing are required.  Are you concerned about performance, for example?  Security?  Or just basic functionality, as the question seems to suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have asked about tests approach in general - think about the non functional tests that are needed for your project:
Desktop / mobile and different mobile compatibility - how will the site will look like in them?
performance - how quickly the pages will load? and how much will take to submit the form you mentioned and continue?
User experience - is the page clear and the operations are simple and easy to understand? 
maintenance - how easy is to update the site?
For more ideas - you can go to the following [link](http://thetesteye.com/posters/TheTestEye_SoftwareQualityCharacteristics.pdf) and select the ones that apply to you:

Comment: Your link is dead.

Comment: Link works for me. However just google "the test eye software quality characteristics" and you'll find this sheet full of ideas.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any other things I am missing from my list?

You mentioned "Click on all "link" elements, making sure they are valid, e.g. there is no 404." Is that good enough? Shouldn't you check that the links actually go where they are intended to go?

Are you checking for consistency on all the pages? Should they all have the same look & feel?

Are you looking for missing elements? Is there a way to logout? Does Help exist? Is there a 404 page? Does the site have a favicon?

Are you planning to perform crossbrowser testing? Performance testing? Load testing?

What about security testing?

Are you required to do testing of any content? Or just the "Q&A" section? What about testing for broken images?

Do you have any formal Requirements at all that will guide some of your testing? If not, this might help: http://www.allthingsquality.com/2010/04/there-are-always-requirements.html

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not really think as much as you suggested here.